# Mix hyperref and varioref

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, varioref

I like that `hyperref` gives me results like

```
\ref{eq:first-equation}   % yields "equation (1)"
```

and that `varioref` gives results like

```
\vref{eq:first-equation}  % yields "1 on the following page"
```

but I would like even more if the resulting `vref` yielded "equation (1) on the following page," to distinguish from tables, etc.

Is there any way to get this to happen?

My current preamble includes

```
% ...
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{refstyle}
% ...
\usepackage[unicode=true]{hyperref}
% ...
```

in this order, if it matters.

---

When I remove `refstyle` and switch it out for `cleveref`, all of my `\eqref`s break. For example

```
\eqref{4-range-of-validity}
```

used to produce `equation (8)` but now produces `(??)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use `refstyle`; instead, load (in that order!) the `varioref`, `hyperref`, and [`cleveref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) packages in the preamble and use `\vref` in the text body. (For cross-references without page information, use `\cref` instead of `\ref`.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}

\begin{document}

Some text. See \vref{eq:test}.

\clearpage

\begin{equation}\label{eq:test}
a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Okay, but now my normal `\ref{eq:test}` is just showing `(1)`, not `equation (1)`; how do I fix this?

Comment: Also `\vref{eq:test}` produces `equation (??) on the preceding page` for me

Comment: @WChargin Ad 1: See the last sentence of my answer. Ad 2: Without a minimal working example, I can't say what's going on.